# How is this cube root continued fraction generated?

Tags: radicals, continued-fractions

I'm looking at the examples on the Wiki Page [Generalized Continued Fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#Roots_of_positive_numbers) .  The introduction to general root-finding states a formula:

[image: basic formula]

But then, looking at the second example for cube root of 2,

[image]

What am I missing?  If x = 5 and y = 3, I get $ z = 5^3 + 3$ which is clearly not correct, and then the statement $2z-y = 253$ makes no sense either.

If I keep y = 3, this implies a "new" z = 128 and the calculation is actually acting on $128^{\frac{1}{3}}$ , leading to m = 5 .  Is that what's implied here?

Comment: That Generalized Continued Fraction is pretty much useless because it converges at a snail's pace. The right way to obtain the higher order roots is to go with the Simple Continued Fractions. [Here](https://medium.com/@omer.kasdarma/the-curious-world-of-simple-continued-fractions-part-iv-higher-order-roots-a0f6c294dd0) I had posted a detailed explanation.

Comment: @Redu no doubt!  I just wanted to understand in general how to interpret the expansion.  Sometimes (hard to believe :- )  I do math stuff just for fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the suggested parameters: $x=5,y=3$, for $n=3$ we have $z=128=2^7=2^6.2$. Then, to express $2^{1/3}$ as a continued fraction, it is sufficient to take $m=1$, as
\begin{equation}
 2^{1/3}=\frac{128^{1/3}}{2^2}=\frac14\left( 5^3+3 \right)^{1/3}
\end{equation}
The proposed continued fraction with these parameters reads
\begin{equation}
 \left( 5^3+3 \right)^{1/3}=5+{\cfrac {3}{3\cdot5^2+{\cfrac {2\cdot3}{2\cdot5+{\cfrac {4\cdot3}{3\cdot3\cdot5^2+{\cfrac {5\cdot3}{2\cdot5+{\cfrac {7\cdot3}{5\cdot3\cdot5^2+{\cfrac {8\cdot3}{2\cdot5+\ddots }}}}}}}}}}}}
\end{equation}
Then several simplifications are in order: divide the numerator and denominators of the first fraction by a factor $6$, the second one by $2$, the third one by $3/2$,the fourth one by $2$, then $3/2$, $2$,... It gives
\begin{equation}
 2^{1/3}=\frac{\left( 5^3+3 \right)^{1/3}}{4}=\frac54+{\cfrac {1/2}{2\cdot5^2+{\cfrac {2}{5+{\cfrac {4}{2\cdot3\cdot5^2+{\cfrac {5}{5+{\cfrac {7}{5\cdot2\cdot5^2+{\cfrac {8}{5+\ddots }}}}}}}}}}}}
\end{equation}
which is the proposed result.

The second form comes from the decomposition given in the same page
\begin{equation}
\sqrt[n]{z^{m}}=x^{m}+{\cfrac {2x^{m}\cdot my}{n(2x^{n}+y)-my-{\cfrac {(1^{2}n^{2}-m^{2})y^{2}}{3n(2x^{n}+y)-{\cfrac {(2^{2}n^{2}-m^{2})y^{2}}{5n(2x^{n}+y)-{\cfrac {(3^{2}n^{2}-m^{2})y^{2}}{7n(2x^{n}+y)-{\cfrac {(4^{2}n^{2}-m^{2})y^{2}}{9n(2x^{n}+y)-\ddots }}}}}}}}}}
\end{equation}
Remarking that $2x^n+y=2z-y$, here $2x^n+y=253$ which immediately gives
\begin{equation}
 2^{1/3}=\cfrac54+\cfrac14{\cfrac {2\cdot5\cdot 3}{3\cdot253-3-{\cfrac {(3^{2}-1)3^{2}}{3\cdot3\cdot253-{\cfrac {(2^{2}3^{2}-1)3^{2}}{5\cdot3\cdot253-{\cfrac {(3^{2}3^{2}-1)3^{2}}{7\cdot3\cdot253-{\cfrac {(4^{2}3^{2}-1)3^{2}}{9\cdot3\cdot253-\ddots }}}}}}}}}}
\end{equation}
Here, by dividing the numerators and denominators of all the fractions by $3$, it comes
\begin{equation}
 2^{1/3}=\cfrac54+{\cfrac {1\cdot5/2}{253-1-{\cfrac {3^{2}-1}{3\cdot253-{\cfrac {2^{2}3^{2}-1}{5\cdot253-{\cfrac {3^{2}3^{2}-1}{7\cdot253-{\cfrac {4^{2}3^{2}-1}{9\cdot253-\ddots }}}}}}}}}}
\end{equation}
noting that $n^2\cdot3^2-1=(3n-1)(3n+1)$, we obtain the given expression.

Comment: Good to know I was at least on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

Also, the source article for calculating nth roots has been relocated since the original website for the source has expired. When I cited the source, I made a minor modification to simplify the decomposition, which the author (Manny Sardina) approved.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1828426)

Comment: This is more comment...